# Finding value of a in a probability density function when mean is given.

Tags: statistics

It is given that a continuous random variable $x$ is distributed uniformly over the interval $[0,a]$. The probability density function is $f(x)$ is $\frac{1}{a}$. It is also known that the mean of the variable is $2$. What is the value of $a$?

Comment: Can you express the mean of the variable via the parameter $a$ value?

Comment: You really should include in your post an indication of how you approached the Question.  Posting a problem without attempting to solve it yourself may make Readers reluctant to respond.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. One may [recall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_(continuous)) that if the probability density function of the continuous uniform distribution $X$ is
$$
  f(x)=\begin{cases}
  \frac{1}{\beta - \alpha} & \mathrm{for}\ \alpha \le x \le \beta, \\[8pt]
  0 & \mathrm{for}\ x<\alpha\ \mathrm{or}\ x>\beta
  \end{cases}
$$ then one has
$$
E(X)=\frac{1}{2}(\alpha+\beta).
$$
Can you apply it here?

Comment: From this the answer comes out to be 4. But what if I do $$\int_{0}^a a*1/a = 2 $$ Is this wrong? Because I get a = 2 by doing this?

Comment: @kriti_sharma You can't do $\int_{0,\infty}a\cdot \frac1a $ rather $\int_{0,\infty}x\cdot f(x) \:dx$ giving here $\int_{0,a}x\cdot \frac1a\:dx=\frac{a}2 $ that is $\frac a2=2$. Do you get it?

Comment: Surely just looking at a graph of UNIV(0,2) you don't think $\mu = 2.$